# How I can modify my code to can use front camera for scanning QR code

Tags: java, android, qr-code, vision

I'm using android vision to scan QR code in my app and everything is ok but now I want to make my app can scan QR code by opening front camera not back camera.

Code of scanning screen:

```
public class BarCodeScanActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BarcodeReader.BarcodeReaderListener {

private String TAG = OperatorBarCodeScanActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private Context mContext;
private View currentView;
private Activity currentactivity;
private BarcodeReader barcodeReader;


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.barcode_reader_activity);

    mContext = getApplicationContext();

    barcodeReader = (BarcodeReader) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.barcode_scanner);

}

@Override
public void onScanned(Barcode barcode) {
    // playing barcode reader beep sound
    barcodeReader.playBeep();
    final String scannedCode = barcode.displayValue;

}

@Override
public void onScannedMultiple(List<Barcode> barcodes) {

}

@Override
public void onBitmapScanned(SparseArray<Barcode> sparseArray) {

}

@Override
public void onScanError(String errorMessage) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mContext.getString(R.string.barcode_error)+" " + errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onCameraPermissionDenied() {
    finish();
}}
```

Layout of this screen is looking like the following:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:id="@+id/scanningContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/barcode_scanner"
        android:name="info.androidhive.barcode.BarcodeReader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:auto_focus="true"
        app:use_flash="false" />

    <info.androidhive.barcode.ScannerOverlay
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:line_color="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:line_speed="6"
        app:line_width="4"
        app:square_height="200"
        app:square_width="200" />
</LinearLayout>
```

How I can update my code to can use Camera Surface and then call front face camera?

Thanks.

Comment: Post your `BarcodeReader` fragment plz.

Comment: @JakirHossain I updated my post take a look please

Comment: This is highly dependent on the barcode reader library you're using. Help yourself by googling for "<library-name> change camera" and you should find a couple of useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

I did the Googling for you - this is the method you need to use:

https://github.com/ravi8x/Barcode-Reader/blob/master/barcode-reader/src/main/java/info/androidhive/barcode/camera/CameraSource.java#L237

Unfortunately, this API is not exposed by the `BarcodeReader` fragment, so you need to fork it's implementation and adapt this:

https://github.com/ravi8x/Barcode-Reader/blob/master/barcode-reader/src/main/java/info/androidhive/barcode/BarcodeReader.java#L251

Think about making a public fork, make this setting configurable and publish a pull request to the original author, so other people can benefit from your extension as well.

Comment: I googled already for the used library and I saw your posted links already and I know I should use CAMERA_FACING_FRONT from Camera Surface but I sticked in how can do that bu keeping my code working as most as possible, I'm trying again